# Modeline to hide specific lines

Tags: modeline

I have a long .csv log file that I regularly append data to. I am usually interested in editing last 10 entries or so. I suppose vim modelines do not support Ex commands due to security reasons. Is there a workaround to make this Ex command a modeline in vim so that whenever the *specific* .csv file is opened, it shows only last 10 entries (like `head` but in vim).

```
:1,$-10fold
```

Comment: not possible via modelines. However should be possible using a `Buf(Win)Enter` autocommand

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file is `/usr/bar/foo.csv` I would do:

```
augroup FoldSpecificLog
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead /usr/bar/foo.csv 1,$-10fold
augroup END
```

Comment: Maybe an augroup instead of autocmd! ?